# How to start Machine Learning with python programming?

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning

I know the concepts of python programming. And I heard that with python machine learning is more compatible. So, I want to start the machine learning using python. I am a novice in machine learning.(just want to start from scratch)
How will I start towards this??

Comment: [Scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) is a great tool to build machine-learning algorithms in Python. You may find some interesting things just by navigating the website. 
This [book](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html) could also be a good start to understand neural networks (a very popular technique in machine-learning). Plus, this [page](http://machinelearningmastery.com/a-tour-of-machine-learning-algorithms/) is going through most used techniques of "machine-learning" and could be a good start for you.

Comment: thanks Gregoire G.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to learn theoretical sutff including maths/stats/data mining etc...

The best way is - depending on ur current background - probably the very famous [Andrew Ng Coursera Course on Machine Learning](https://coursera.org/learn/machine-learning). I honnestly don't think there's a faster/easier way. Youtube may be a good help as I already found tons on ML/stats related videos.

Answer (score 2):

Having solid knowledge on statistical background of machine learning, I think is more essential. Numpy, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn, would be some useful tools in python for machine learning.

Answer (score 2):

One of the best resources I found when I first started using Python for machine learning was Sebastian Raschka's [Python's Machine Learning](https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/python-machine-learning) book.

I also used a variety of different Udemy tutorials, such as this [one](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4614-6849-3). They're great for building confidence, but they generally only show you generic use cases, with data sets that are typically much cleaner than the ones you'll see in real life.

However, make sure that you are understanding the conceptual basis of what you are doing. Anyone can go import scikitlearn and crank out some predictions, but what separates an amateur from a professional in this being able to write your own custom algorithms, understanding the edge cases, and lower-level nuances (ie. when to use L1 vs. L2 regularization, or whether your data pattern means you can implement a RBK vs linear support vector machine), etc. For that, I'd highly recommend picking up a few machine learning and predictive analytics textbooks, such as [Applied Predictive Modeling](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4614-6849-3) by Max Kuhn and Kjell Johnson.

Finally, there are a variety of great podcasts to listen. One pretty accessible one for beginners to familiarize yourself with core data science principles is the [The Data Skeptic](https://dataskeptic.com/).